# json value set in session storage not working across browsers

Tags: javascript, json, session-storage

I'm setting a variable in session storage to hold a json value like this

```
sessionStorage.setItem("Client", JSON.stringify({"filterType":"customers","filterValue":""}));
```

This works in Chrome but in Firefox it doesnt.
When i inspect the value after the call it appears as `{"filterType":0,"filterValue":""}`

Anyone any ideas why this might happen? I can't seem to get it to work all the time

Comment: hmm, did you try this : sessionStorage.setItem("Client", JSON.stringify({filterType:"customers",filterValue:""}));

Comment: It works fine on both Chromium and Firefox (51.0.1 - 64-bit). Your JSON object is a valid one. There shouldn't be any problems here.